# How to trigger onchange when the page load

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to trigger on change event when the page load I tried to do `$("#formtype").change();` but it doesn't work

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select name="form" id="formtype" class="form-control">
    <option value="A">Form A</option>
    <option value="B">Form b</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#formtype').on('change', function () {
    //  alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
    if(this.value == "A") {
      $('#form1').show();
      $('#form2').hide();
    } else {
      $('#form1').hide();
      $('#form2').show();
    }
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to trigger a change event?  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try to trick the DOM into thinking that an event has occurred.  If you want to execute code when the page loads, just execute it.  Something like this:

```
// define the function
var toggleElements = function () {
    if($('#formtype').val() == "A") {
        $('#form1').show();
        $('#form2').hide();
    } else {
        $('#form1').hide();
        $('#form2').show();
    }
};

// set the handler
$('#formtype').on('change', toggleElements);

// execute the function when the page loads
$(document).ready(toggleElements);
```

Comment: but when the page load the id of form 2 that appear , and the value selected is of the form 1

Comment: @AhmedImadTouil: I had a mistake in copying/pasting your code.  It's been corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

Why not put it the code you want to run in a function, then call that function?  Something like this will work:

```
$('#formtype').on('change', function() {
  doStuff();
}); 

function doStuff() {
  if($('#formtype').val() == "A") {
    $('#form1').show();
    $('#form2').hide();
  } else {
    $('#form1').hide();
    $('#form2').show();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    doStuff();

})
```

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/5jLx6q8b/

Comment: 2 solution same problem : when the page load Div of form 2 appears and the value selected of form2

Comment: You didn't provide enough HTML in your question, you'd need to change `this` to the element you want to interact with, in this case `$('#formtype')`

Answer (score 2):

try to execute this code inside the document ready event's function:

```
$("#formtype").trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly in the binding of the events

```
$('#formtype').on('change', function () { }).trigger("change");
```

or

```
$('#formtype').on('change', function () { }).change();
```